# Magic mouse stopped working while installing Mojave

Tags: installation, macos-mojave

I tried to downgrade from Catalina to Mojave, I erased Macintosh HD drive and all steps were working good.

I shutdown the pc and opened it while holding "option" key and select Mojave to install. By (usb flash drive).

Now, the mouse stopped working and I can't select the disk. Only the keyboard is working but still can't select with it. 
I tried all keys, but they're dead!

I can't post images because I'm a new member.

I'm stuck now! I don't what should I do.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Here is a solution that worked for me, in case someone stumbles on this question.

In the screen you are referring to, when you are asked to select the disk, if the mouse is not working you can proceed by using voiceover. To activate it, press cmd+f5. To navigate the various options, press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+arrow keys.

With <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+up/down arrow, you go out/in of a grid/table (for example you will need it to select the disk).

Once you manage to select the disk you want for the installation, press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to confirm and go to the next screen.

Hopefully this should be enough to get you through the installation process, after which the mouse should go back to working normally.